# Imput Dim is incompatable with layer lstm_3

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

```
x_train (11712, 131)
y_train (11712, 3)

x_test (2928, 131)
y_test_oh (2928, 3)

embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, W2V_SIZE, weights=[embedding_matrix], 
input_length=SEQUENCE_LENGTH, trainable=False)

model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=True ))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

When I am adding more than 1 LSTM layer, it is giving me an error saying 
'Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_6: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2'

Comment: From what I saw, your mode should run fine as you added return_sequences=True in your param. If I were you, i’ll try check if the output from embedding layer is actually rank 3 or not.

Comment: @ChompakornCChaichot, i got this. Thanks.